# Adjacency Matrix analysis in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, adjacency-matrix

Say I'm looking at how users utilize a particular webpage per day (or week) amongst 5 tabs that are available on the page that we will just name `Tab 1, Tab 2, Tab 3, Tab 4, Tab 5` . `Tab 1` is the main entry point and users could go from `Tab 1` to any of the other 4 Tabs and do whatever they need to do and then go on to another tab if they choose (i.e. `Tab 1 -> Tab 2 -> Tab 5` or `Tab 1 -> Tab 3 -> Tab 2 -> Tab 5 -> Tab 4` , doesn't matter the order). I want to get the number of users who go through different Tab paths (sort of like a funnel analysis except that in this case it doesn't matter what the progression and end goal is). I was thinking creating an adjacency matrix with weights would provide some insight on user usage on how they progress through the webpage to form some sort of network graph? Currently my dataframe looks like this (rough estimate):

```
userid  | tab    | datestamp   | timestamp
1        'Tab 1'  2020-01-03    2020-01-03 11:07:48.000
1        'Tab 3'  2020-01-03    2020-01-03 11:08:32.000
1        'Tab 2'  2020-01-03    2020-01-03 11:10:15.000
2        'Tab 1'  2020-01-05    2020-01-05 14:04:33.000
2        'Tab 5'  2020-01-05    2020-01-05 14:06:24.000
3        'Tab 1'  2020-01-05    2020-01-05 14:03:11.000
3        'Tab 4'  2020-01-05    2020-01-05 14:07:24.000
```

and this continues onwards for multiple months of data. Would adjacency matrix be the right approach to this? or would something else be better? And if it is better, would it be beneficial to classify the timestamps with Session numbers to filter out situations where a user visits a tab but doesn't visit any other tab after that?. Or is it better to just follow a standard funnel approach where I calculate visits per a designated path of tabs I expect a user would go through.

Additionally if it is possible to do it via an adjacency matrix, I'd like to do it on all users and then separate ones on a user aggregate level.

Comment: There are a lot of questions here and this is pretty broad. Can you narrow the scope down to a concrete, answerable question? You might want to look into networkx, which has page rank algorithms, if that's what you're after here. Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen basically I want to map all the paths between tabs across all users (as well on a per user level) along with how often these paths occur.

Comment: OK, cool. Have you tried writing some code for that that you could share?